# Twilio chat synchronization on re-connection

Tags: android, chat, twilio

Lets say that a twilio chat client(TC1) on an Android/iOS device has already received M messages from another chat client(TC2).

Due to network issues, TC1 stays disconnected for D mins, during which TC2 sends 3 messages.

When TC1 comes back online, will it receive these 3 messages automatically in quick succession ?

If yes, what if D is in hours or days ?

In which cases can the app rely on the twilio sdk to auto synchronize on disconnections and which are the cases when the app needs to explicitly synchronize the channel or fetch latest messages manually and merge it with what it has so far ?

Comment: I see you've asked a couple of questions about reconnections in the Twilio Chat API and not got an answer yet. I work at Twilio but don't know the answer myself right now. I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who will either be able to answer you or get you in touch with the Chat team who can enlighten us all.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted twilio and here is what they replied:
[image]